# 1D gstat's variogram

Tags: r, gstat

I want to convert this code from 2D to 1D to estimate the variogram. Also, I want to make a loop to do that code for multiple csv files.

```
#Load package
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(gstat)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
library(classInt)
library(RStoolbox)
library(spatstat)
library(dismo)
library(fields)
library(gridExtra)
library(Hmisc)

#Load Data
dataFolder <- ".....\\Desktop\\variogram\\"

V1 <- read.csv(paste0(dataFolder,"0.csv"), header= TRUE)

#define x & y variables to coordinates
coordinates(V1) = ~x+y

# Variogram
v.v <- variogram(V1$Z~ 1, data = V1, width=1000)

# Intial parameter set by eye estimation
m.v <- vgm(0,"Exp",3000,0)

# least square fit
m.f.v <- fit.variogram(v.v, m.v)
p1 <- plot(v.v, pl=F, model=m.f.v, main= "Z")
p1
```